# Using an animation with reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, reloaddata

In my UITableView instance, I'm moving the cell to index:0 and reloading the data. The problem is that the cell "snaps" to the top (due to the reloadData, i think). I'm wondering if i can move the cell up, then apply reloadData a few seconds later. Heres my code:

```
[_toDoItems removeObject:todoItem];

[_toDoItems insertObject:todoItem atIndex:0 ];





[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:origIndexPath toIndexPath:0];

[self.tableView endUpdates];

sleep(1);
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

the problem with this is, after the method is called, everything pauses for 1 second, then the "snap" animation occurs.

Comment: Whats the use of `sleep(1);`? Remove it.

Comment: `sleep()` should never be used. It blocks all threads including the main one which handles all of the visuals. This is why you see it waiting a second, then snapping. The snapping is just waiting for its tread to be unlocked. Also since `reloadData` does not have any animations it will give a "snapping" effect.

Comment: my logic was, that the cell would get moved to the top; then it the sleep would delay the reloadData 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You first tell the tableView to expect updates with `beginUpdates`. Then update the relevant sections (if your tableView has only one section then just pass zero for the section number). Here's where you specify the animation - you can play around with it to get the effect that you want. After that you call `endUpdates` on the tableView. The typedef for `UITableViewRowAnimation` specifies:

```
typedef enum {
   UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
   UITableViewRowAnimationRight,
   UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
   UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
   UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
   UITableViewRowAnimationNone,
   UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,
   UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic = 100
} UITableViewRowAnimation;
```

Play around to see which one you want. Even selecting `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`can have a nice effect sometimes. Depending on how many sections you have you can use `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

Table update code below:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: @brain If you find any of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question.**

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(briefPause) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I used the above in the same method as

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates]
....
```

but I made a new function, briefPause which is just:

```
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: It actually works but i would recommend to use less time:  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(briefPause) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

It will still work, but look smoother

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:origIndexPath
                                                       inSection:0]]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0
                                                       inSection:0]]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: And as others have mentioned above, don't use sleep(). I forbid it! :)

Comment: even tweaking withRowAnimation: to something else, it doesnt really fix the problem. It prevents the weird snap/flicker but the cells just instantaneously appear at the top without animation. :/